# VueJS: como acessar dados de um v-for dentro de um método?

Tags: vue.js

Tenho o seguinte problema, preciso manipular algumas variáveis que estão no meu **data**, através de um click, que está dentro de uma lista **(v-for)**. Porém só consigo criar a condição diretamente dentro do click, não consigo fazer as comparações através de um método.

Segue um exemplo:

**js**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    exemplo1: false,
    exemplo2: false,
    carros: [
      {
      "tipo": "Passeio",
      "cor": "Azul",
      "detalhe": "Sim"
      },
      {
      "tipo": "4x4",
      "cor": "Preto",
      "detalhe": "Não"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    verificaDetalhe: function(){
        console.log(this.carros.detalhe);
    },
  },
})
```

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="carro in carros">
    <h1>Tipo: {{carro.tipo}}</h1>
    <h2>Cor: {{carro.cor}}</h2>
    <a href="#" v-on:click="verificaDetalhe()">Detalhe</a>
    <a href="#" v-on:click="if(carro.detalhe == 'Sim'){ exemplo1 = true}">Detalhe2</a>
  </div>
  <div v-if="exemplo1">Exemplo1</div>
  <div v-if="exemplo2">Exemplo2</div>
</div>
```

Ao clicar no **a** "Detalhe2" do primeiro carro da lista, a condição é satisfeita, porém como eu tenho várias regras, eu queria utilizar um método pra isso.

Como posso fazer essa verificação da lista através de um método? Tentei utilizar um forEach mas sem sucesso.

Segue um link do codepen pra ajudar a enxergar o que estou tentando: https://codepen.io/haykou/pen/eGzdLL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa passar o carro:

```
<a href="#" v-on:click="verificaDetalhe(carro)">Detalhe</a>
```

E receber na outra ponta:

```
methods: {
  verificaDetalhe: function(carro){
    console.log(carro.detalhe);
  },
},
```